# bouncing ball algorithm issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t33dfnn7/)

I'm tying to make the ball which is a `div` bounce to the left once coming from the right but it still come back to the right side,  i know there is too many similar questions who gave a solution to this but they all implementing `canvas`  which is not my case , the way I'm doing it seems right to me but like you can see in the live demo the ball still come back to the right , here is the code :

```
var  speed = 15,
     directionTop = 1,
     directionLeft = 1;
setInterval(function(){


     var ballElement = document.getElementsByClassName('ball')[0],
         containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName('mainDiv')[0],
         playersTestRebounce = document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0];


     if (ballElement) {

        var boxLeftPos = ballElement.offsetLeft,
            boxRightPos = boxLeftPos + ballElement.offsetWidth,



            offsetContainer = containerElement.offsetWidth + 40;
            offsetContainerTop = containerElement.offsetTop;


            if (boxRightPos > offsetContainer) {
                directionTop = 1;
                directionLeft = -1;
            }

            if (boxLeftPos < -40) {
                directionTop = 1;
                directionLeft = 1;
            }

                if (ballElement.offsetTop > playersTestRebounce.offsetTop && ballElement.offsetTop < (playersTestRebounce.offsetTop + 70) && ballElement.offsetLeft < (playersTestRebounce.offsetLeft + 12)) {                  
                        directionTop = 1;
                        directionLeft = 1;
                }

            if (ballElement.offsetTop > 390) {
                directionTop = -1;  
                directionLeft = 1;  
            }

            if (ballElement.offsetTop < 0) {
                directionTop = 1;
                directionLeft = 1;
            }


            ballElement.style.left = (boxLeftPos + speed * directionLeft) + 'px';
            ballElement.style.top = (ballElement.offsetTop + speed * directionTop) + 'px';




            /*cordinators = getPos(ballElement);
            console.log("ball X : "+ cordinators.y + " ball Y :" +cordinators.x);*/

            /*random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 376) + 6);

            if (boxLeftPos < -40 || boxRightPos > offsetContainer) {
                ballElement.style.top = random + 'px';
            } */


     }  
}, 100);
```

Comment: You should not change the left/right motion when bouncing against the top or bottom wall; also you should not change the up/down motion when bouncing against the left or right wall.

Comment: but it seems to work this way when the ball come from the left to the right and not in the other direction !

Comment: it will work for the first bounce left to right becaus you set directionLeft = 1 when you bounce bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic bouncing can be reduced to this http://jsfiddle.net/52b261e2/1

```
if (ballElement.offsetTop > 390 ||ballElement.offsetTop <0) {
    directionTop *=-1;  
}

if (boxLeftPos <0 ||boxRightPos>600) {
    directionLeft *=-1;  
}
```

when you reach bottom or top it changes 1 in -1 and -1 in 1
same goes for left to right

*edit forgot to update fiddle